# Db2 query com between e partition by

Tags: sql, db2

Eu preciso de uma ajuda com essa query abaixo, ela não está fazendo o que eu gostaria. Ela faz tudo perfeito. Porém quando utilizo o between ele me retorna um erro. Gostaria de uma ajuda sobre a query.

```sql
SELECT UNIDADE, MATRICULA, NOME, CURSO, ESCOLA, DTATU, HRATU, STATUS,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NOME ) AS CONT
FROM (

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATRICULA ORDER BY DTATU DESC,HRATU DESC) AS RN,   
row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY NOME ) AS rid, UNIDADE, MATRICULA, NOME, CURSO, ESCOLA, DTATU, HRATU, STATUS 
FROM MOV_PROTOCOLO WHERE MATRICULA!='' ) AS t WHERE MATRICULA!=''and RN = 1) WHERE V.CONT BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

Algo assim:

```
PLACE   CODE      STATUS CONT                 
------- --------- ------ -------------------- 
001     41309014  OK     1                    
001     31121810  OK     2                    
001     41309634  OK     3                    
001     31414303  OK     4                    
001     41461487  OK     5                    
001     41207203  OK     6                    
001     41444868  OK     7                    
001     31344046  OK     8                    
001     41447131  OK     9                    
001     41083326  OK     10
```

Comment: Então eu só gostaria que essa query acima me retornasse os primeiros 10 valores. Utilizando o between

Comment: Acredito que agora está traduzido :)

Comment: Qual erro está retornando?

Comment: Se sem o between funciona a querie trazendo algum resultado por que você não utiliza " v.cont >= 0 and v.cont <= 10"